# Existing pages to subpages on trac

Tags: trac

Is it possible to make existing page a subpage of some other existing page on Trac? When using the "parentToBe/SubToBe = markup, Trac notifies on a new page creation that page SubToBe is maybe relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having WIKI_RENAME permission every wiki page has a button 'Rename' at the bottom of the page. You click and change e.g. "Test" to "parentToBe/Test2" there, and it's just moved to be a subpage of "parentToBe" then.